# Get count of each id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have the following tables

dbo.employee

```
id          name      position_id      phone
-----------------------------------------------   
1           Gosho         1            5623565
2           Pesho         2            095656
3           Misho         3            0984654
```

dbo.repairs

```
id          service_id  client_id   employee_id    dt      price
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ------
3           1           2           1           2003-05-03 4.54
4           2           1           2           2013-05-03 3.55
5           1           2           1           2003-05-03 4.54
6           2           1           2           2013-05-03 3.55
7           1           2           1           2003-05-03 4.54
8           2           1           2           2013-05-03 3.55
9           1           2           1           2003-05-03 4.54
10          2           1           2           2013-05-03 3.55
```

I want to view how many repairs there are for each employee.

The result that I am aiming for should be something like this:

```
employee_id  repairs_count
--------------------------
1             4
2             4
```

Here is my code that i came up with

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(r.employee_id)
FROM
    repairs r
LEFT JOIN 
    repairs e ON r.id = e.id
WHERE 
    r.id = e.id
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Tip: When LEFT JOIN, have the join conditions in the ON clause - and only once.

Comment: So...what's the point of joining `repairs` to `repairs` on their `id`???  You'll get the exact same record.

Answer (score 4):

Group by `employee_id`. Aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group

```
select employee_id, count(*) as repairs_count
from repairs
group by employee_id
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about employees with repairs -- as in your sample results -- then you don't need a `join`:

```
select r.employee_id, count(*) as cnt
from dbo.repairs r
group by r.employee_id;
```

If you want *all* employees, even those with no repairs, then use a `left join`:

```
select e.id, count(r.employee_id) as cnt
from dbo.employees e left join
     dbo.repairs r
     on e.employee_id = r.employee_id
group by e.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

using a JOIN to add more informations from the employee table

```
SELECT 
   employee_id = e.id,
   e.name, 
   repairs_count = COUNT(r.id)
FROM
   dbo.employee e
   LEFT JOIN
   dbo.repairs r ON e.id = r.employee_id
GROUP BY
   e.id, e.name
HAVING
   COUNT(r.id) > 0
```

Comment: That HAVING clause makes no difference,.

Comment: @jarlh And for EmployeeID = 3?

Comment: No difference. (count(*) counts rows, no matter if there are null values or not.)

Comment: what is the use for the `having` in this query ?

Comment: Employee ID 3 has no repairs. Question does not ask for employees with zero repairs. So it's filtered out

Comment: The HAVING clause restricts the result to only include rows with an r.id count > 0. I.e. only employees with repairs are returned. (Could also been achieved with an INNER JOIN.)

Comment: I did not noticed that in the expected result from the OP employees without repairs where left out

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this

group by

```
select e.id,
       e.name,
       e.position_id,
       e.phone,
       count(*) as repairs_count
from   employee e
  left outer join repairs r on e.id = r.employeeid
group by e.id, e.name, e.position_id, e.phone
```

NOTE: if you want to leave out employees that have no repairs, simply replace the left join by an inner join

or by subquery

```
select e.id,
       e.name,
       e.position_id,
       e.phone,
       (select count(1) from repairs r where r.employeeid = e.id) as repairs_count
from   employee e
```

I would go for the first option since the optimizer will have it easier to use indexes and its easier to leave out employees that have no repairs should you want that